# Cannot download .lst files from web server using C# Web Client

Tags: iis, download

I am downloading files from a web server using the C# WebClient. My code is of the form

```
 using (var Client = new WebClient()
 {
     Client.DownloadFile(Source, Target);
 }
```

This all works fine if the file extension of the file to download is .xml or .txt, but if it is .lst I get a 404 error says 'Not Found' even though I know the file is present. I tried adding the extensions to the list of allowed extensions in IIS but still get the same error. .lst files are shown in Explorer as 'MASM Listing' files - are these blocked from being downloaded?

I also tried using the HTTP Client to download the file but with the same results. Short of changing the name of the file after downloading, is there any way to allow to download of .lst files.

Thanks

Comment: make sure you have .lst mime type added in the iis with the text/plain or application/octet-stream
assign the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the directory where you have .lst file type is available.
make sure .lst is not blocked in the Request Filtering settings.

Comment: set the header using this code: `using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    // Add headers if needed
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Your User Agent String");

    var response = await client.GetAsync("url to .lst file");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var fileBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        File.WriteAllBytes("path to save the file", fileBytes);
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle error response
    }
}`

Comment: You need to open up IIS log files and see what are sub status codes for those 404 errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code

Comment: Perfect - that fixed it. Thanks

Comment: could you please share which suggestion help you to resolve the issue